# How to convert this date 'Wed Mar 9 09:48:09 PST 2016' to 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss' format?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, momentjs, datetime-format

I am trying to convert datetime value from this format `Wed Mar 9 09:48:09 PST 2016` into the following format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss`

I tried to use [moment](https://github.com/moment/moment) but it is giving me a warning.

```
"Deprecation warning: moment construction falls back to js Date. This is discouraged and will be removed in upcoming major release. Please refer to https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1407 for more info.
Arguments: [object Object]
fa/<@http://localhost:1820/Resources/Scripts/Plugins/moment.min.js:7:9493
ia@http://localhost:1820/Resources/Scripts/Plugins/moment.min.js:7:10363
Ca@http://localhost:1820/Resources/Scripts/Plugins/moment.min.js:7:15185
Ba@http://localhost:1820/Resources/Scripts/Plugins/moment.min.js:7:15024
Aa@http://localhost:1820/Resources/Scripts/Plugins/moment.min.js:7:14677
Da@http://localhost:1820/Resources/Scripts/Plugins/moment.min.js:7:15569
Ea@http://localhost:1820/Resources/Scripts/Plugins/moment.min.js:7:15610
a@http://localhost:1820/Resources/Scripts/Plugins/moment.min.js:7:41
@http://localhost:1820/Home/Test:89:29
jQuery.event.dispatch@http://localhost:1820/Resources/Scripts/Jquery/jquery.min.js:5225:16
jQuery.event.add/elemData.handle@http://localhost:1820/Resources/Scripts/Jquery/jquery.min.js:4878:6
"
```

according to https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1407 I should not be trying to use moment() to do this since it is not reliable.

How can I reliably convert the `Wed Mar 9 09:48:09 PST 2016` into the following format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss`?

Comment: I'm not going to create an answer, but you should look into [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date). You'll learn more about what you're doing. If you need other formats that is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using `Date.toJSON()` , `String.prototype.replace()` , <strike>`trim()`</strike>

```js
var date = new Date("Wed Mar 9 09:48:09 PST 2016").toJSON()
           .replace(/(T)|(\..+$)/g,  function(match, p1, p2) {
             return match === p1 ? " " : ""
           });

console.log(date);
```

Comment: Thank you for that code. This code works perfectly in a modern browser. But when I try to use it in an IE8 comparability mode I get an error. Object doesn't Support this property or method.

Comment: @MikeA The issue was `String.prototype.trim()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim#Browser_compatibility ; see updated post

Comment: Yes, this will yield the requested format - but it will also convert to UTC - which was not asked for.

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged your question with [moment](/questions/tagged/moment), I'll answer using moment.

First, the deprecation is because you are parsing a date string without supplying a format specification, and the string is not one of the standard ISO 8601 formats that moment can recognize directly.  Use a format specifier and it will work just fine.

```
var m = moment("Wed Mar 9 09:48:09 PST 2016","ddd MMM D HH:mm:ss zz YYYY");
var s = m.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"); // "2016-03-09 09:48:09"
```

Secondly, recognize that in the above code, `zz` is just a placeholder.  Moment does not actually interpret time zone abbreviations because there are just [too many ambiguities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zone_abbreviations) ("CST" has 5 different meanings).  If you needed to interpret this as `-08:00`, then you'd have to do some string replacements on your own.

Fortunately, it would appear (at least from what you asked) that you don't want any time zone conversions at all, and thus the above code will do the job.